# Pass data to TabBarControllers after intialization?

Tags: swift

How would I do something like this?

```
viewControllers!.forEach
        {
            $0.view
            $0.m = self.m // error here
        }
```

In each tabbarcontroller I defined m, yet this is not working.

I need it done through this as I initialize every tab by this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is $0, the shorthand for the first parameter (i.e. a viewController in this case), is always immutable in a closure.  There are a few other things to address to...

First of all you will need to subClass UIViewController to allow you to create/access the `m` property.  At the most basic level this will be:

```
class MyVC: UIViewController {
  var m: Int = 0   //giving a default value to save a .init in the example
}
```

The you will need to create MyVC view controllers, rather than standard UIViewControllers within your AppDelegate / SceneDelegate.

At which point you can adapt your original code to set the `m` property within each view controller:

```
if let count = tabBarController.viewControllers?.count {
    for i in 0 ..< count {
        if let vc = tabBarController.viewControllers?[i] as? MyVC {
           vc.view // as per the original, but can't see any point in it
           vc.m = m
        }
    }
}
```